# Using Cookies under SSL & Load Balancing Environment

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis, cookies, load-balancing

We have a load balancer and two IIS servers behind that. We want our application to work under SSL. Our load balancer has SSL certificate, but our IIS servers don't.

When we open our web application through browser, we see that it works under SSL. But we are having difficulties when we use cookies. For example: our forms authentication cookie does not working as expected. We log in to application successfully but after that, if the user clicks to a link that needs authentication, the application behaves like the user is not authenticated. We tried adding Secure flag for our cookies but the problem did not solved.

Do we need to have SSL certificates for all the IIS servers behind load balancer? Or do we have other modifications (other than adding Secure flag) for cookies to work under SSL?

Everything works fine if we disable SSL.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What are these difficulties?

Comment: @AnibalDíaz I added an explanation.

Comment: If you want to maintain a session across different servers you will need to either use a 'Sticky Sessions' solution on the LB or defer the session to something like Redis. Give this a google and you'll find loads of information on the topic.

Comment: @donners45 We already have a sticky sessions solution on LB. The problem seems about the cookies under ssl. Because the exact same application works fine without ssl configuration on the same environment. Do you have any suggestions about that?

Comment: @anilca Apologies for being off-topic.. You may want to check your machineKey in your IIS/web config. We had an issue whereby one server was unable to read the 2nd server's secure cookie because they had different keys. We had to manually create a machine key (using IIS) and apply this to each server behind the LB. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772287(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: @donners45 machine keys solved our issue too. Thank you very much.